# Unable to Lazy load modules in Angular2(RC-6)

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement lazy loading of feature modules in my sample angular2 application.

My application has a root module and two feature modules.

Path of Root module and routing files are

```
app/public/scripts/app.module.ts
app/public/scripts/app.routing.ts
```

Path of feature module and it's routing for which I want to implement lazy loading are

```
app/public/scripts/modules/user/app.user.module.ts
app/public/scripts/modules/user/app.user.routing.ts
```

Below is app.routing.ts code

```
'use strict';

import {Routes , RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';

const appRoutes : Routes = [
{path: 'ausers' , loadChildren: 'scripts/modules/user/app.users.module#UsersModule' }
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Below is app.user.routing.ts code

```
'use strict';

import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes , RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

//-- import components , directives and pipes
import { AppUsersComponent } from './app.users.component';


const UserRoutes :Routes = [
{path: 'ausers/showusers' , component: AppUsersComponent }
]

export const userRouting: ModuleWithProviers =  RouterModule.forChild(UserRoutes);
```

When user clicks below link in application

routerLink="ausers/showusers"

it is displaying below error

> Failed to parse SourceMap: http://localhost:3000/scripts/BehaviorSubject.js.map
>   Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call >enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
>   EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected >token <
>       Evaluating http://localhost:3000/scripts/modules/user/app.users.module
>       Error loading http://localhost:3000/scripts/modules/user/app.users.module

I am using webpack for module loading and bundling.
Any idea what could be the reason for this error?

Comment: Thats the only error msg? Anyway.. child-routes are relative.. so change your child route from `ausers/showusers` to `showusers` .

Comment: changing path did not help , updated more information about error in question

Comment: @j2L4e , the solution that you provided in this link worked..

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the path of the module relative to `src/`:

```
{path: 'ausers' , loadChildren: 'app/public/scripts/modules/user/app.users.module#UsersModule' }
```

Also lazy-loading was buggy with webpack on RC6, which was fixed in [#11837](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/11387) and RC7.